# Filtering objects by checking if multiple entries in many-to-many table exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three tables: `listings`, `amenities`, and `listing_amenities`. I have a filter where users can filter listings by amenities, and in my controller I take in their filter as an array of `amenity` descriptions. I am trying to filter for listings which have ALL of those `amenities`. Currently, I can filter, but it only succeeds to check if `listings` have at least ONE of the provided `amenities`.

Current query:

```
  scope :filter_by_amenities, ->(amenities) { # amenities is array of descriptions
    includes(:listing_amenities)
      .where(listing_amenities: {
               :amenity_id => (
                 Amenity.where(:description => amenities)
               )
             })
  }
```

How can I modify the query to only return listings which have ALL of the amenities, rather than at least one?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using class method and querying on the resultant records iteratively.

```
  def self.filter_by_amenities(amenities)
    amenity_ids = Amenity.where(:description => amenities).pluck(:id)
    records = self.all
    amenity_ids.each do |amenity_id|
      record_ids = records.includes(:listing_amenities).where(listing_amenities: {:amenity_id => amenity_id)}).pluck(:id)
      records = records.where(id: record_ids)
    end  
    records
  end
```